# django clean method on model form

Tags: django, django-forms

I've only used the out-of-the box Django forms API. I'm now trying to validate form field data on a django model form - update_profile. My model contains the validators, where (and why) do I perform a clean or save in order to provide field level messaging for the end-user? Currently, my error dict is empty.

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email'), max_length=254, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(_('username'),max_length=15, unique=True,
        validators=[RegexValidator('^[_a-z0-9]+$', message= '15 characters max. Username must be a-z(lowercase), 0-9, can contain underscore', code='invalid_username')])
    about_me = models.CharField(_('about me'),max_length=140)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars/', blank=True, null=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=50, blank=True)
        phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex='^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message='Phone number must be between 9 and 15 digits')
    phone_number = models.CharField(_('phone_number'),max_length=15,  blank=True,
        validators=[phone_regex])
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('staff'), default=False)
```

views.py

```
def update_profile(request):
    user=request.user
    if user.is_authenticated == True:
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomUserChangeForm(request.POST, instance=user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Your profile was successfully updated.')
            return redirect('update profile')
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Please correct the error below.")

    form = CustomUserChangeForm(instance=user)
    return render(request, 'profile.html', {'form': form})
```

forms.py

```
class CustomUserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = CustomUser
    fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'about_me','phone_number')
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your view.

Comment: thanks - formatting fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the invalid form to the user. You should put your instantation of the empty form into an `else` block so it only happens on GET.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CustomUserChangeForm(request.POST, instance=user)
    if form.is_valid():
        ...
else:
    form = CustomUserChangeForm(instance=user)
return render(request, 'profile.html', {'form': form})
```

Now in the template `{{ form.errors }}` will display your validation errors.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this code.  You discard previously validated form, create new form and pass it to the template.

```
form = CustomUserChangeForm(instance=user)
return render(request, 'profile.html', {'form': form})
```